# Extend header to top of page with CSS rounded corners

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage with a wrapper using rounded corners.  The first thing in the wrapper is the page header, but there is a white space above it, where the corners are.  I want the blue header to start right at the top of the wrapper, so there is no white space at the top.  I don't know if this is possible, but any help would be appreciated!  Here is the (simplified) code.  I used inline CSS to post this.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
         <h1>Test Page</h1>

    </div>
    <!--header-->
    <div id="nav"> <a href="index.html">Home</a>  <a href="index.html">Link 1</a>  <a href="index.html">Link 2</a>  <a href="index.html">Link 3</a>  <a href="index.html">Link 4</a>

    </div>
    <!--nav-->
    <div id="main">
        <p>This is the test page.</p>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <!--main-->
</div>
<!--wrapper-->
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #999999;
}
h1 {
    line-height: 200%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
a {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    color: #000000;
}
#wrapper {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    min-width: 760px;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
#header {
    background-color: #40ebff;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
#nav {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #ffdab2;
    padding: 5px;
}
#main {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

**FIDDLE > http://jsfiddle.net/znfa0Lkf/**

Comment: Please demo in a JSfiddle.net example.

Comment: demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nLsufhdv/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v1xrt7vg/)

You needed to add `margin-top:0;` to that `h1` style, as it was forcing it down.

Then, you needed to add

```
border-top-left-radius:25px;
border-top-right-radius:25px;
```

to `#header`.

Alternatively, add `overflow:hidden;` to `#wrapper` instead. As [Woodrow Barlow said in the comments:](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3961271/woodrow-barlow)

> some browsers will draw a sliver of the underlying element if you try to perfectly match rounded corners on top of each other (the rendering isn't perfect)

*Side note: you don't need to add `px` to something if it's set to `0`. For example, you can just have `margin-top:0;`, not `margin-top:0px`*.

Comment: This is perfect!  I didn't think that I would need to add a border to #header as well after adding the margin-top:0; to the h1, but it makes perfect sense now!!

Comment: i recommend hiding the overflow of `#wrapper` rather than adding a radius to `#header`, because some browsers will draw a sliver of the underlying element if you try to perfectly match rounded corners on top of each other (the rendering isn't perfect).

Comment: I agree with "Woodrow Barlow", giving radius to different tag just to get the same style is not a good practice, rather you should give overflow property to the parent div.

Comment: Thanks all, I'll add the overflow:hidden;!!

Comment: Just to update you...the fix to add "overflow" "header" will not help!!! here is the fiddle with this solution> http://jsfiddle.net/znfa0Lkf/1/

Comment: You would have to add "overflow:hidden" to "wrapper" to fix the issue... here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0w646ba1/

Comment: Yeah, I did figure out that the overflow:hidden needs to go on #wrapper. Thanks for the follow up everyone.

Answer (score 2):

add this in you code

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

and add to you wrapper `overflow:hidden;`

Answer (score 1):

As has been suggested, you would benefit from a simple [CSS reset](http://www.cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/). By default, the browser adds certain paddings and margins to certain elements -- by explicitly negating that, you can define your own paddings and margins. Another advantage is that since the "defaults" might differ from browser to browser, you get more consistent results across the board.

The reset is simple. Add this to the top of your CSS:

```
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

And add couple changes to make your page the way you intended it. First, we'll add `margin:10px` (adjust as desired) to the `#wrapper` (this makes it so your rounded corner box is how it was before rather than smashed into the top of the page). Next, add `overflow:hidden` to the `#wrapper`. Since the `#header` doesn't have rounded corners, it would normally have the square corners flood out of the `#wrapper`, but the `overflow:hidden` prevents that.

Here is a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rcaoy84z/).

Note that you don't need to use the CSS reset if you don't want to. If you'd prefer, you can just add a `margin-top:0` to the `h1` selector. In this case, you wouldn't need to add the `margin` to the `#wrapper`, but you would still want to set the `overflow:hidden`. Here is a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kpwdoyg2/) of that version.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

By default there is margin and padding over several elements including body so you're seeing the space there and setting margin and padding value to 0 with all selector (*) will remove the margin and padding value or say there is no space in your document.

Comment: Thanks, but I still want the rounded corners at the top of the page.  Setting the margin and padding to 0 removes them.

Comment: @user3507530 if thats the case you should post your code in fiddle where we can find whats going wrong in it.

Comment: You should then apply padding or margin to your particular element like you have h1 to manage...

Comment: Iam not lazy enough  :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue 1 > margins around your "Wrapper"

You are getting the margins around your "Wrapper" due to default margins in "`<body>`"
All you need to do is remove default Margin and Padding from "`<body>`"

#### Issue 2 > margins above the "Blue Header"

Add `margin-top: 0px;` Since its taking the default margin for `<h1>`

#### Issue 3 > Radius is removed when remove margin from H1

Add `overflow:hidden;` to "#wrapper" so `<h1>`and **`header`** stays inside **`wrapper`** and doesn't overrule the style.

Here is the Final Fix added:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #999999;
    margin:0 auto; /*FIX ADDED*/
    padding:0; /*FIX ADDED*/
}
h1 {
    line-height: 200%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px; /*FIX ADDED*/
}
    


 #wrapper {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    min-width: 760px;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
    border-radius: 25px;
    overflow:hidden;  /*FIX ADDED*/
}
```

### Here is the Working Fiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/0w646ba1/

**Sorry, missed to add the fix for space above header.

Comment: Probably because the Fiddle doesn't do what OP asks, which is to move the blue header to the top. Your Fiddle still shows whitespace above the blue header.

Comment: Yeah I missed to read the header issue initially! thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

```
#header h1
{
    background-color: #40ebff;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin:0;
    border-top-left-radius:25px;
    border-top-right-radius:25px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4g1j45L9/1/